# (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iframe, version

I have converted a .net 1.2 project to 4.5 and the error i am getting is :-
The base class includes the field 'ifUC', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe). 
I have search internet enough to know HtmlGenericControl is not supported in 4.5 framework so changed all the iframes intialisation to System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe in project yet it throws error

the targetframe work is 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded a webforms project from 4.0 to 4.6.2. I did a clean and rebuild and the error went away. I also found this site that has more info about the error. https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmliframe-is-not-compatible-with-the-type-of-control-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmlgenericcontrol/